# How to hide .directory on Desktop?

Tags: 20.04, window, hidden-files

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20, I noticed there's now a `.directory` file on my Desktop with the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Icon=user-desktop
Type=Directory
```

As I hate clutter, I deleted it. However, with it removed, now the alt+tab task switcher no longer works. When I restored the file, then the task switcher worked again. So for some odd reason this file is seemingly required to the window manager to work.

How do I hide this file on my desktop without breaking the window manager?

Comment: What is the exact name of the file? `*.directory` files have nothing to do with "Alt+Tab switcher".

Comment: @karel No. I usually want to see hidden files. Just not on my desktop.

Comment: @FedKad It's just `.directory`.

Comment: that's weird, the .directory file only defines the folder type (much like W*ndows's desktop.ini), it shouldn't break your alt-tab menu.

Comment: Hidden files' names start with a dot. If the name of the file is .directory, it is already a hidden file. You can type **Ctrl + h** to see or to hide hidden files.